# Selecting gridview row with a radiobutton in ASP.Net

Tags: asp.net, gridview

I would like to have a gridview with a radiobutton column in order to
select just a row and do some task. I added a templatefield but when I
run the application, it let me select all rows, but what I want is
select only one. How can I do that? I mean, I want the radiobutton
column to work as a group.

Comment: So what you are asking is to disable all the other rows as soon as one row's radiobutton is selected?

Comment: In the future, please use meaningful titles. "gridview in asp.net" is a really broad title.

Answer (score 2):

Microsoft made a [Tutorial for that](http://www.asp.net/data-access/tutorials/adding-a-gridview-column-of-radio-buttons-vb)

Comment: That tutorial was extremely helpful

Answer (score 0):

Did you set the "GroupName" property? Something like this, for example:

```
<asp:GridView runat="server" ID="MyGridView">
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Select">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:RadioButton runat="server" ID="myRB" GroupName="MyRadioButton" />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Some Other Column">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <%-- other stuff here --%>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

You could also replace the `<asp:RadioButton>` with a standard `<Input>` field, and then bind the `Value=""` property to something unique (like a Row ID, for example).

Answer (score 0):

Try to instantiate the radiobutton markup as a literal inside your template, for example like this:

```
  internal class RadioButtonTemplate : ITemplate, INamingContainer
        {
            public void InstantiateIn(Control container)
            {
                Literal radButton = new Literal();
                radButton.ID = "RadioButtonMarkup";
                radButton.Text = "<input type='radio' name='myRadioButton' id='myRadioButton' value='<%# Eval(" + "CategoryID" + "%>'/>";
                container.Controls.Add(radButton);
            }
        }
```

Comment: @SpikeX: As opposed to your solution?

Comment: My solution was more of a suggestion or a fix, assuming that he already had existing code that just needed to be fixed.